# Integrate Google fonts into Android app title

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-support-library, google-fonts

I'm new to mobile app development and was curious on what is the recommended way to integrate Google fonts into an app, more specifically into the title of the TitleBar.

I've found some older official google developer guide that uses a support library and FontRequest but since I heard that things change frequently and it seems that this issue isn't documented very well, I'm curious what would be the currently preferred way to integrate the fonts.

And also the second part to make them appear in the TitleBar.

I'd appreciate anything that helps me solve this issue, even if it is just a hint on where to look at.

Thank you in advance